# Programmatically scroll UIScrollView using subview element

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uilabel, superview

I would like to know how to access a UIScrollView using a subview UILabel.

I have tried to access the UIScrollView using `.superview`; however I am now receiving an error

```
No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'scrollRectToVisible:animated:'
```

The code I am using looks like this

```
- (void) SymbolButtonPressed:(NSString *)selectedString {

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:currentlySelectedTag];

// perform scrolling here, figure out what view your uilable is in.
    float newPosition = label.superview.contentOffset.x+label.frame.size.width;
    CGRect toVisible = CGRectMake(newPosition, 0, label.superview.frame.size.width, label.superview.frame.size.height);

    [label.superview scrollRectToVisible:toVisible animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The superview of a `UILabel` is of type `UIView` and so does not respond to the method you are trying to call. You can cast the superview as a `UIScrollView` so that Xcode can see the methods and properties you are trying to access. You should also check if the superview responds to the method.

```
if([label.superview respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollRectToVisible:animated:)]) {
    [(UIScrollView *)label.superview scrollRectToVisible:toVisible animated:YES];
}
```

Given your sample code you will also need to cast the superview to get contentOffset

```
float newPosition = ((UIScrollView *)label.superview).contentOffset.x+label.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: XCode dosnt like that code either. Looks like I will have to find another way to access it. its jus that I have multiple UILabels inside Mutiple scrollviews that are placed inside UITableViewCells.. So I have a table of UIScrollviews as their cells and im trying to figure out which UIScroll view to scroll.

Comment: @HurkNburkS I have expanded my answer to include casting the superview to a UIScrollView as well - which is probably what Xcode was complaining about. Try that.